# Python extract zipfile

Tags: python, zip, extract, python-zipfile

I want to extract txt files from zip file to Desktop and i got it with the code below but if zip files have file which has text files, how i extract these text files from file to Desktop?

```
import zipfile


def abc(path_to_zip_file, directory_to_extract_to):

    with zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip_file, 'r') as zip_ref:
         zip_ref.extractall(directory_to_extract_to)

path_to_zip_file ="zip file path"
directory_to_extract_to = "Desktop path"
z = zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip_file)

abc(path_to_zip_file, directory_to_extract_to)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import zipfile, os, shutil
myZip = zipfile.ZipFile('visualvm_207.zip')


for file in myZip.filelist:
    if file.filename.endswith('.txt'):
        source = myZip.open(file)
        target = open(os.path.join(directory_to_extract_to, os.path.basename(file.filename)), "wb")
        with source, target:
            shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your reply.
The file is created with the code you sent, but the text files in the file are not extracted to the desktop.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: So the text files still remain in the file, but I want to extract the text files from the file to the desktop.

Comment: you mean, that a folder is created?

Comment: Yes, but i want to extract text files from this folder. btw this folder is not zip.

Comment: Did you set directory_to_extract_to?

Comment: yes but what is "wb" ? i dont understand this

Comment: with ```open(filename, mode)``` you open a file. mode is either ```r -> read, rb -> readbytes, w -> write, wb -> write bytes```. In your case, you open the file for writing, so ```w``` and ```wb``` is applicable

Comment: Your last code succeeded. Really thank you so much.